# if statement with $_GET['part']

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I'm trying to get one page with 3 parts with the if state ment. Please look thru the code, and help me.

And I would be glad if you dont tell me to lear this or that, cuz that is what i'm bin doing.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['part'])&&!empty($_GET['part'])){
   if($_GET['part'] = '1'){
       ## Part 1
       ## Some content
       echo '1';
    }else if($_GET['part'] = '2'){
       ## part 2
       ## Some content
       echo '2';
    }else if($_GET['part'] = '3'){
       ## Part 3
       ## Some content
       echo '3';
    }

    }else{
       header('Location: index.php?part=1');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Equality comparison in conditions should be `==` not `=`. So you should have `$_GET['part'] == 'value'`.

Comment: instead of one equal sign which is for assignment use two equal signs which is for comparison!

Comment: Thanks, that was helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this be easier?

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['part'])) {
    case '1':
       ## part 1
       ## Some content
       break;
    case '2':
       ## part 2
       ## Some content
       break;
    case '3':
       ## Part 3
       ## Some content
       break;
    default:
       header('Location: index.php?part=1');
}
?>
```

Comment: It might be. but why would not my code work? :S 

But the switch looks mush better.

Comment: @Magnus, your code would not work and it is explaied in comments!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['part'])&&!empty($_GET['part'])){
    if($_GET['part'] >=1 or $_GET['part'] <=3)
        header('Location: index.php?part = $_GET['part']');
    else
        header('Location: index.php?part = 1');
?>
```